# react-native-maps is rendering a blank map on some devices in production

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

**Problem** 
I've built an android app using Expo, which uses react-native-maps to render a map.
The map is rendering properly in development. In production, it renders on some devices but not on others. In the cases where it doesn't, it displays a blank map with a 'Google' logo.
[image]

**Steps I've taken to solve the issue** 

1.) I've read that incorrect API configuration can cause this issue, so checked my `app.config.js` file and Google Cloud console to make sure that I had set it up correctly - which I think I have:

**app.config.js**

```
    android: {
      googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json",
      icon: "./assets/icon.png",
      package: "********",
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: "****************"
        }
      },
      versionCode: 3
    },
```

**Cloud configuration**

Here's a screenshot of how I've set up the Google Maps API - note that the API key is the same as the one in my `app.copnfig.js` file:
[image]

2.) I had also read that this issue could be solved by adding the following permissions to `app.config.js`, but it didn't fix the problem:

```
      permissions: [
        "INTERNET",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
      ]
```

3.) Lastly, I thought it might be a styling issue, so I added a `flex:1` property to the map container:

```
  map: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    flex:1,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        borderRadius:26,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 2,
      },
      android: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        borderRadius:26,
        elevation: 4,
      }
    })
  },
```

For context, here's the whole component displaying the map:

**GigMap.tsx**

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { mapStyle } from "../util/mapStyle";
import { useGigs } from "../hooks/useGigs";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { mapProps } from "../routes/homeStack";
import { Switch } from 'react-native-paper'
import { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";

type MapScreenNavgationProp = mapProps['navigation']

interface Props {
    navigation: MapScreenNavgationProp
}

const GigMap:FC<Props> = ({ navigation }):JSX.Element => {
  const [selectedDateMs, setSelectedDateMs] = useState<number>(Date.now());
  const [isSwitchOn, setIsSwitchOn] = useState(false);
  const gigs = useGigs();


  //generates current date in format DD/MM/YYYY
  const selectedDateString:string = useMemo(() => {
    const formattedDate = format(new Date(selectedDateMs),'EEE LLL do Y')
    return formattedDate
  }, [selectedDateMs]);

  const currentDay:string = useMemo(() => {
    const formattedDay = format(new Date(selectedDateMs),'EEEE')
    return formattedDay
  },[selectedDateMs])

  const currentWeek:string = useMemo(() => {
    const formattedDay = format(new Date(selectedDateMs),'LLLL do Y')
    return formattedDay
  },[selectedDateMs])

  //Filtering through gigs to return only current day's gigs
  const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => {
    const formattedGigDate = format(new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds * 1000), 'EEE LLL do Y')
    return formattedGigDate === selectedDateString;
  });

  const freeGigsToday = gigsToday.filter((gig) => {
    return gig.isFree === true
  })

  const gigsToDisplay = isSwitchOn ? freeGigsToday : gigsToday
  
  //increments date by amount
  const addDays = (amount:number):void => {
    setSelectedDateMs((curr) => curr + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * amount);
  };

  const onToggleSwitch = () => setIsSwitchOn(!isSwitchOn);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View testID="gigMapHeader" style={styles.headerText}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText_main}>{currentDay}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.headerText_sub}>{currentWeek}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.imageText}>
        <Text style={styles.subHeader}>Tap on the</Text>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require("../assets/map-pin-new.png")}
        />
        <Text style={styles.subHeader}>
          icons on the map to see more gig info
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: -41.29416,
            longitude: 174.77782,
            latitudeDelta: 0.03,
            longitudeDelta: 0.03,
          }}
          style={styles.map}
          customMapStyle={mapStyle}
          provider = {PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        >
          {gigsToDisplay.map((gig, i) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                key={i}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: gig.location.latitude,
                  longitude: gig.location.longitude,
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("GigDetails", {
                    venue: gig.venue,
                    gigName: gig.gigName,
                    image: gig.image,
                    blurb: gig.blurb,
                    isFree: gig.isFree,
                    genre: gig.genre,
                    dateAndTime: { ...gig.dateAndTime },
                    ticketPrice: gig.ticketPrice,
                    tickets: gig.tickets,
                    address: gig.address,
                    links: gig.links,
                    gigName_subHeader: gig.gigName_subHeader
                  });
                }}
              >
                <Image  style={styles.imageMain} source = {require('../assets/map-pin-new.png')}/>  
              </Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonOptions}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(-1)} style={styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={36} color="#000000" />
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: "NunitoSans", color: "#000000",marginLeft:'8%' }}>
            Previous day
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(1)} style={styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretright" size={36} color="#000000" />
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: "NunitoSans", color: "#000000",marginRight:'8%' }}>
            Next day
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style = {styles.buttonAndSwitch}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("List")}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>List View</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style = {styles.switch}>
            <Switch value={isSwitchOn} onValueChange={onToggleSwitch} color = '#377D8A' />
            <Text style = {styles.switch_text}>Free Events</Text>
          </View>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
};

const {width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight} = Dimensions.get('window')
const mapWidth = screenWidth * 0.9 //this sets width to 90%
const mapHeight = mapWidth /0.91 //this set height  based on the figma map aspect ratio of 0.91



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // flexDirection: "column",
    // alignItems: "center",
    flex:1
  },
  map: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    flex:1,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        borderRadius:26,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 2,
      },
      android: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        borderRadius:26,
        elevation: 4,
      }
    })
  },
  marker: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  markerText: {
    color: '#000',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  mapContainer:{
    marginTop: '5%',
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    width: mapWidth,
    height: mapHeight,
    flex:1,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        borderRadius:26,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 2,
      },
      android: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        borderRadius:26,
        elevation: 4,
      }
    })
  },
  gigInfo: {
    // backgroundColor: '#68912b',
    // marginTop:20
  },
  gigInfo_text: {
    fontSize:10,
    color:'black',
    fontFamily:'NunitoSans',
    paddingTop: 25,
    textAlign:'center',
    fontWeight:'bold'
  },
  gigInfo_text_genre: {
    color: "white",
    fontFamily: "Helvetica-Neue",
    transform: [{ translateY: -5 }],
  },
  headerText: {
    color: "black",
    fontSize: 25,
    marginTop: '0%',
    marginLeft: '7%',
    fontFamily: "NunitoSans",
    marginBottom: 10,
    
  },
  headerText_main: {
    fontFamily: "NunitoSans",
    fontSize:25,
    lineHeight:34.1
  },
  headerText_sub: {
    fontFamily:'LatoRegular',
    size:14,
    lineHeight:16.8
  },
  callout: {
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    backgroundColor: "azure",
  },
  buttonOptions: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop:'4%',
    width:'100%'
  },
  buttonOptionsText: {
    margin: 5,
  },
  image: {
    height:20,
    width:14,
    marginHorizontal:3
  },
  imageMain: {
    height:35,
    width:23,
    marginHorizontal:3
  },
  imageText: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginLeft:'7%',
    marginTop:27
  },
  touchable: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  subHeader: {
    fontFamily: "LatoRegular",
    color: "#747474",
    size: 12,
    lineHeight: 17.04,
  },
  button:{
    flexDirection:'column',
    width:115,
    height:37,
    marginLeft:'7%',
    backgroundColor:'#377D8A',
    borderRadius:8,
    justifyContent:'center',
    marginTop:'6%'
  },
  buttonText: {
    color:'#FFFFFF',
    textAlign:'center',
    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans',
    fontSize:16,
    lineHeight:22
  },
  buttonAndSwitch:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    marginBottom:'6%'
  },
  switch:{
    marginRight:'6%',
    // transform: [{translateY:7}],
    marginTop:'4%'

  },
  switch_text: {
    fontFamily: 'LatoRegular',
    fontSize:10,
  }
});

export default GigMap;
```

So far nothing has worked, I suspect that maybe it's an issue with the SHA key or API key/android version/something screwy with react-native-maps.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Issue might be with the API key, to get API key for maps from google, it is required to provide SHA key, you must have used SHA key of the debug keystore/jks. Play store re-signs the application with its own keys while uploading app to store. If this is the case, you should use the SHA key from the play store console.

Follow these steps to find the SHA key,

1. Open Play Console and go to the Play App Signing page (Release > Setup > App integrity).
2. Scroll to the “App signing key certificate” section and copy the fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate.

Comment: Hey there - I don't think my app has a keystore. However the SHA-1 key in Google Play is the same as the one being used for the Google Maps API configuration, and is the same SHA-1 key as listed in the 'Credentials' section on Expo. Any suggestions?

Comment: upload Expo's SHA-1 certificate fingerprint on GCP (project's dashboard > Configure > click Credentials > Application Identifiers > click your project's package name and under Android Keystore).
You may refer [this](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4393#issuecomment-1407583378)

Comment: This is true to my case. Thanks brother. 

Everytime we do production release the "app signing key certificate" renewed, so u need to add the SHA to allowed apps in google cloud console